# Spring + hibernate + form

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I have an User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{
private enum Sex {MALE, FEMALE};

@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@NotNull
private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping("/addUser")
public String showHomePage(Map<String, Object> map) {
    map.put("user", new User());
    return "addUser";
}
```

and form in jsp file

```
<form:form method="post" action="add" commandName="user"> 
     <form:input path="name"/>
     <form:input path="password"/>
     <form:input path="confirm-password"/>
</form:form>
```

This form generates error because there is no `confirm-password` field in `User.class`. I could of course add `confirm-password` field as `@Transient` to `User.class`, but what if I would like to add captcha field to my form. Is there a different way to add additional field to form?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536024/spring-mvc-requestparam-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice to use your models as form entities. You should have a bean or form class to get the data from the view and another for the model.

Reason is that they have different responsibilities thus needing to to be mapped to different classes. They are often very similar, but that separation promotes a cleaner coding and avoids security breaches, as a user could try to use your model variables from the view by using a request tamperer for example(like fire bug).

These small differences between them like the one you listed above justify the creation of another class.

Comment: To avoid lot many classes floating around we have this concept of annotating a class and use it for both the purpose. There will lot of code revolving in preparing the conversions. Again its a choice.

Comment: I agree with you, there are other variables to be considered here, but IMHO I would make that separation in a standard solution.